# C linked list inserting node at the end without replacing previous node

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I'm having some trouble with my insertion method for a linked list in C. It looks like every insertion i make only replaces the previous one. so at the end the list always contains only one cell . i think the problem starts with "insertToEndList" function. Do you see any reason why it's failing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct listNode{
    int* dataPtr;
    struct listNode* next;
}ListNode;

typedef struct list
{
    ListNode* head;
    ListNode* tail;
}List;

void deleteFromBeginnigOfList (List *list);
void deallocateListCell (ListNode *cell);
void freeList (List *list);
void printList (List *list);
void insertDataToBeginningList (List *list, int num);
void addToBeginningList (List *list, ListNode *cell);
List merge (List list1, List list2);
ListNode *createCell (int num);
void addToEmtyList(List *list, ListNode *cell);
void addToEndList(List *list, ListNode *cell);
void insertDataToEndList(List *list, int num);
void makeEmptyList(List *list);
List getList();
void main()
{

    List lst1, lst2, mergedList;

    lst1 = getList();
    lst2 = getList();
    mergedList = merge(lst1,lst2);

    printf("Merged list:\n");
    printList(&mergedList);

    freeList(&lst1);
    freeList(&lst2);
    freeList(&mergedList);

}

List getList()
{
    List res;
    int size, num, i;

    makeEmptyList(&res);

    printf("Please enter the number of items to be entered:\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    printf("Please enter the numbers:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        insertDataToEndList(&res, num);
    }

    return res;

}
void makeEmptyList(List *list){
    list->head=list->tail=NULL;
}
void insertDataToEndList(List *list, int num){

    ListNode *cell_to_add= createCell (num);
    if (list->head==NULL)
        addToEmtyList(list, cell_to_add);
    else
        addToEndList(list, cell_to_add);
}
ListNode *createCell (int num){
    ListNode *cell=(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    if (!cell)
    {
        printf("memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    cell->dataPtr=&num;
    cell->next=NULL;

    return cell;
}
void addToEmtyList(List *list, ListNode *cell){
    list->head=list->tail=cell;
}
void addToEndList(List *list, ListNode *cell){
    list->tail->next=cell;
    list->tail=cell;
}
List merge (List list1, List list2){
    List merge_res; 
    ListNode *curr_cell1=list1.head, *curr_cell2=list2.head; 
    ListNode *cell_to_add;

    makeEmptyList (&merge_res); 
    while (curr_cell1 && curr_cell2) 
    {
        if (*(curr_cell1->dataPtr)>*(curr_cell2->dataPtr))
        {
            insertDataToEndList(&merge_res, *(curr_cell1->dataPtr));
            curr_cell1=curr_cell1->next;
        }
        else
        {
            insertDataToEndList(&merge_res, *(curr_cell2->dataPtr));
            curr_cell2=curr_cell1->next;
        }
    }
    while (curr_cell1)
    {
        insertDataToEndList(&merge_res, *(curr_cell1->dataPtr));
        curr_cell1=curr_cell1->next;
    }
    while (curr_cell2)
    {
        insertDataToEndList(&merge_res, *(curr_cell2->dataPtr));
        curr_cell2=curr_cell2->next;
    }
    return merge_res;
}

void printList (List *list){
    ListNode *curr_cell=list->head;

    while (curr_cell)
    {
        printf("%d, ", *(curr_cell->dataPtr));
        curr_cell=curr_cell->next;
    }
}
void freeList (List *list){
    while (list->head)
        deleteFromBeginnigOfList(list);
}
void deleteFromBeginnigOfList (List *list){
    ListNode *cell_to_delete=list->head;
    list->head=list->head->next;
    if (list->head==NULL)
        list->tail=NULL;
    deallocateListCell (cell_to_delete);
}
void deallocateListCell (ListNode *cell){
    free(cell->dataPtr);
    free (cell);
}
```

Comment: [TL;DR!](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TL;DR). Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us instead.

Comment: `list->head->next==NULL`  this condition in `if` you assume list is empty but list can have 1 node only. That should be taken care of .You should check if `head` is null or not for empty list.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how this code executes at all without segfaulting. In `getList`, you first call `makeEmptyList` which sets `list->head=NULL`, then you call `insertDataToEndList` which accesses `list->head->next` (i.e. dereferencing the null pointer `list->head`). When I compile and run the program it crashes at this point.

Comment: [Please don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3233393).

Comment: does have to be singly linked? a doubly liked list with a sentry node is a lot easier to verify for correctness. see [example](http://pastebin.com/HC1DLK4M)

Answer (score 1):

In this function, you access to list->head->next but on the first
insertDataToEndList, list->head == NULL since you used makeEmptyList so
the result will be a segmentation fault. Also, you want to check if the
list is Empty so do list->head == NULL instead.

```
void insertDataToEndList(List *list, int num)
{    
    ListNode *cell_to_add= createCell (num);
    if (list->head->next==NULL)
        addToEmtyList(list, cell_to_add);
    else
        addToEndList(list, cell_to_add);
}
```

In this method, you have to set the first and the last node of your list,
not the next so replace by list->head and list->tail instead of lis->head->nest.
and list->tail->next.

```
void addToEmtyList(List *list, ListNode *cell)
{
    list->head->next=list->tail->next=cell;

}
```

You can do that instead :

```
ListNode *createCell (int num)
{
    ListNode *cell=(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    if (!cell)
    {
        printf("memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int *temp = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *temp = num;
    cell->dataPtr=temp;
    cell->next=NULL;

    return cell;
}
```

Else, I advise you to do one assignement by line to be more lisible.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors here. Most are relatively simple pointer errors:

In one place you have

```
curr_cell2=curr_cell1->next;
```

where it should be

```
curr_cell2 = curr_cell2->next;
```

In `addToEmtyList`, you have

```
list->head->next=list->tail->next=cell
```

but if the list is empty, then both `head` and `tail` are null. Similarily, the condition in `insertDataToEndList` should check `list->head` and not `list->head->next`.

A more aggravating error is that you're taking the address of a local variable (`num`) and saving it in each cell. Saving the address of a local variable is something you should almost *never* do, since the pointer will become invalid as soon as you leave its scope (in this case, when you leave `createCell`).

What you should do, if you really want to have a pointer to the data, is allocate memory for it separately. I.e.:

```
ListNode *createCell (int num){
    ListNode *cell=(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    int *data = malloc(sizeof(*data));

    if (!cell || !data)
    {
        printf("memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    *data = num;
    cell->dataPtr=data;
    cell->next=NULL;

    return cell;
}
```

Another option is to change `listNode` to contain an `int` instead of an `int*`. Then you'd have

```
typedef struct listNode{
    int data;
    struct listNode* next;
}ListNode;
```

and in `createCell` simply

```
cell->data = num;
```